# Recreating Solidity sha256(this) in python

Tags: solidity, hash

I'm trying to recreate the following solidity statement in python:

sha256(this)

I have the correct hash function, but I don't know how to recreate the input "this"

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`this` should be the contract address, which is conventionally represented encoded in hex, prepended by `0x`.

You probably have to strip the `0x` and turn that into a byte array to feed to your hashing function, so if the contract address is in a variable called `addr`, do something like:

```
from sha3 import keccak_256
from rlp.utils import encode_hex, decode_hex

myhash = keccak_256(decode_hex(addr[2:])).hexdigest()
```